# Stored procedure with transaction inside an EF Core transaction

Tags: c#, stored-procedures, transactions, entity-framework-core, transactionscope

I have a intriguing doubt.

How does a Stored Procedure that uses BEGIN TRANSACTION, COMMIT and ROLLBACK behaves inside a EF Core transaction - BeginTransaction() ?

Will stored procedure commit independently or does it follow EF Core transaction scope?

I'd like the procedure to ignore its own transaction and uses EF Core only.
How can I achieve this?

Comment: Nested transactions don't really exist in SQL Server. Each `BEGIN TRANSACTION` (which includes EF transactions, as those are just translated to regular SQL transactions under the covers) just increases the open transaction count. `COMMIT` decreases it until the whole thing is committed when the count reaches 0, while `ROLLBACK` cancels everything. There is no way, within a single T-SQL batch, to start a separate transaction that somehow ignores the outer transactions (unless you get really tricky with scheduled jobs).

Comment: So, what you're saying there is no impact, is that right? I may use this procedure with no worries calling it from C# transaction?

Comment: Assuming your C# code is correct, yes. (A common mistake is to explicitly call `.Rollback` in a `catch`, for example -- this is wrong as the transaction will be automatically rolled back if not committed, and the attempt at rolling it back twice will generate a new error.) Also, for your own sanity you typically want any procedure that does something with transactions to use `SET XACT_ABORT ON` at the beginning, otherwise some errors that you would expect to abort the transaction don't.